# Issue with Static Django files on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-staticfiles

I have deployed by Django project as a Heroku app, but can not get the static files to work.

settings.py

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)
```

which is exactly what is recommended at [Django and Static Assets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets)

I have set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC to false with,

```
$ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=0 --app mathsproject
```

The file system looks like this,

[image]

which shows that the 'static' directory is in the root of my Django project. But I do not see where the 'staticfiles' directory is? Should this be created somewhere?

When running,

$ heroku logs

I typically get errors showing that the static files are missing. And this is obvious in the browser too.

```
......
2016-07-11T07:39:30.187273+00:00 app[web.1]: Not Found: /static/assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
    2016-07-11T07:39:30.264037+00:00 app[web.1]: Not Found: /static/assets/img/4.png
    2016-07-11T07:39:30.283627+00:00 app[web.1]: Not Found: /static/assets/img/testimonials/1.jpg
........
```

Whitenoise has been enabled by adding, to mathProject/wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mathsProject.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()

application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

To the bottom of settings.py I put

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Running

```
$ heroku run bash
```

and then,

```
$ python manange.py collectstatic --noinput
```

this gives several lines of errors, the last of which is,

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/mathsProject/static'
```

But there is a 'static' directory in 'mathsProject'

Thanks,

Comment: So you disabled collectstatic, but still expect the static files to be collected? Why?

Comment: And have you followed the rest of that doc page, ie enabled Whitenoise?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=0 which I presume means disable_collectstatic is false therefore enabling collectstatic.

Comment: I followed the rest of the doc page and have enabled whitenoise. I will add that now to the question. Thanks

Comment: I doubt the settings work like that: they are usually used to set environment variables, where just the presence of the setting is enough to enable it. Don't set that value unless you need it; for now, do `heroku config:unset DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC`.

Comment: I ran that but no change unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static files are recognised when the 'static' directory is inside the Django project directory, which unfortunately had the same name as the whole Django directory. Both were called 'mathsProject'.

Also I set,

```
$ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

This works for me.

Comment: Hi Shane, I think I'm facing the exact issue as you and I'm at my wits end after hours and hours. What ended up solving this for you? did you change your root folder name?

Comment: That was two years ago I can't remember what I did sorry.